# While Loop for 100 numbers

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, while-loop, sql-query-store

I Would like to create SQL While loop where I can pull thousands of fields based on the 12 digit numbers and within two Columns range. for instance,

If I have 3 columns in a table

```
MasterKeyNumber---BB000Q000000
StartingNumber BB0000000001
EndingNumber - BB000Q00000022
```

I would like to create a while loop which will pull all the numbers from and within the Starting and Ending number and which will show which will also show MasterKey number

For instance,

```
MasterKeyNumber---BB000Q000000
StartingNumber BB0000000001
StartingNumber BB0000000002
StartingNumber BB0000000003
StartingNumber BB0000000004
StartingNumber BB0000000005
StartingNumber BB0000000006
StartingNumber BB0000000007
StartingNumber BB0000000008
StartingNumber BB0000000009
StartingNumber BB0000000010
StartingNumber BB0000000011
StartingNumber BB0000000012
StartingNumber BB0000000013
StartingNumber BB0000000014
StartingNumber BB0000000015
StartingNumber BB0000000016
StartingNumber BB0000000017
StartingNumber BB0000000018
StartingNumber BB0000000019
StartingNumber BB0000000020
StartingNumber BB0000000021
StartingNumber BB0000000022

EndingNumber - BB000Q00000022
```

I can only pull only one or two ranges by using statements like "Between " "AND" but if I have ranges which shows multiple different number and multiple different ranges how do I do it?

For example, my query for pulling one range at a time

```
Select MasterKey, StartingNumber, EndingNumber, from TabelName
where StartingNumber Between 'BB0000000001' AND 'BB0000000022'
```

Which gives only this range but I have thousands of different numbers which will have multiple range like BB0000000004 to BB00000000010 , BB0000000045 to BB0000000066, BB0000000088 to BB0000000099

What should be my while loop query to get all the ranges?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If there's no rhyme or reason to the ranges you're looking for, what would a loop do for you that you can't do with multiple SELECT statements?  I mean, don't you have to type in the "multiple different number and multiple different ranges" anyway?

Comment: I can edit the loop and apply the loop query to thousand other projects I have!

Answer (score 1):

You'll end up at a lot of dead ends if you think about SQL queries in the form of loops and whatnot. Instead think in sets of data and their relationship to each other.

Think about getting all of the ranges that you want to return:

```
SELECT masterkey, startingnumber, endingnumber FROM tablename;
```

Now we have every start and end number that we want to query. We now want to get all of the startingnumbers that appear in that range and it's masterkey. So:

```
SELECT
    tablename.masterkey,
    tablename.startingnumber,
    myRanges.startingNumber,
    myRanges.endingNumber
FROM
    (SELECT masterkey, startingnumber, endingnumber FROM tablename) myRanges
    INNER JOIN tablename ON
        tablename.startingnumber BETWEEN myRanges.StartingNumber and myranges.EndingNumber
```

Here used that initial query to set the start and end range to query the table again. We return the `masterkey` the `startingnumber` that you are interested in and then the `startingnumber` and `endingnumber` that caused us to pull this particular `startingnumber`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but I am having trouble following second half of the answer  FROM
    (SELECT masterkey, startingnumber, endingnumber FROM tablename) myRanges
    INNER JOIN tablename ON
        tablename.startingnumber BETWEEN myRanges.StartingNumber and myranges.EndingNumber When plug in the starting number and ending number in it the query kept lopping in pulling same number over and over

Comment: Aren't you getting your starting and ending number from the `startingnumber` and `endingnumber` already in the table? It's like you want ranges of records, that are derived from your `startingnumber` and `endingnumber`, but are restricted by a starting number and an ending number. And it's that last requirement, I don't know understand enough to connect the dots from my query to your needs.

Comment: Unless I do this Select 
Tablename.MasterKey, 
TabelName.StartingNumber 
myRanges.StartingNumber, 
myRanges.EndingNumber, 
From
( Select MasterKeyKey = 'B00000000020', StartingNumber = 'B0000000021', EndingNumber = 'B00005000530') myRanges
INNER JOIN SameTableName ON
dbo.SameTableName.StartingNumber Between 'B00000000020' and 'B000000000530'  This gave me the full set of range per record.

Comment: But you already can get the full set for a given hard coded range, which is what you did in your question above. The SQL written in my answer will give you a full range for each range in your table, by connecting it back to itself. You could, in the subquery, if you wanted to limit which ranges come back by `masterkey` (for instance) use something like `(SELECT masterkey, startingnumber, endingnumber FROM tablename WHERE masterkey = 'B00000000020') myRanges ...` Now with any "Range" that has that master key, you will have it return the full range back.

Comment: OH YES! YES! YES! Now it works! Thanks a lot! I guess I was just doing something wrong I re run the query applying your original concept and it worked.  There just plenty of records and it's executing each one of them  .

Comment: Oh yes. Depending on the size of your table, this will be a long running query. It's almost a cross join, but stunted by the ranges, so it's a doozie. Glad to hear it's doing what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Again! Would you mind sharing your email so I can email you when I need help? or is it too much to ask? lol

Comment: That's very flattering, but your better off just shooting future questions out here to SO. There are tons of folks ready to help day and night and as long as you stick as much info as you can in the question, you'll probably get a very helpful answer in under 10 minutes.